# If $p^{2}=p^{*}=p$ and $pa^{*}a=paa^{*}=0$, then $a^{*}p+pa=0$.

Tags: c-star-algebras, projection, idempotents, self-adjoint-operators, involutions

Suppose that $p$ is a projection (i.e. $p^{2}=p^{*}=p$) in a C*-algebra $A$. Let $a\in A$ be an element such that $pa^{*}a=paa^{*}=0$. I want to prove that
$$a^{*}p+pa=0.$$
I tried to express $a$ in terms of $p$, but I dont know how to split $a$ from the given identities $pa^{*}a=paa^{*}=0$. Also I think that it possible to prove the (stronger) statement that $a^{*}p=pa=0$. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When $A$ is an operator algebra, we can note that the image of $aa^*$ is equal to that of $a$, so that $paa^* = 0 \implies pa = 0$, which leads to the desired conclusion since $a^*p =(pa)^* = 0$.

Comment: An idea: let $q = 1-p$. Note that 
$$
aa^* = [(p+q)a][(p+q)a]^* = paa^*p + paa^*q + qa^*ap + qaa^*q\\
= qaa^*q = (qa)(qa)^*.
$$
I'm not very well versed in arbitrary $C^*$ algebras, but perhaps this is enough to conclude that $a = qa$, which is equivalent to what we want.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for your reply! Writing $q=1-p$ requires $A$ to be unital I think. But maybe we can pass to the unitization. I’m not sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(pa)(pa)^* = paa^*p = 0$.  However, we have
$$
\|(pa)(pa)^*\| = \|pa\|^2 = 0.
$$
Thus, we have $pa = 0$, as desired.